# How can I remove empty plots?

Tags: python, loops, dataframe, matplotlib

I'm trying to make a new graph each iteration. But I did get a empty plot every loop.
How can I fix it?
It's my code.

> ```
> import datetime
> def make_plot(item, ap2id):
>     ref_data1_pred = res[(res['ITEM'] == item) & (res['AP2ID'] == ap2id) & (res['WEEK'] >= '201701')]['QTY_PRED']
>     ref_data1_real = res[(res['ITEM'] == item) & (res['AP2ID'] == ap2id) & (res['WEEK'] >= '201701')]['QTY_AP2']
>     ref_data1_x = res[(res['ITEM'] == item) & (res['AP2ID'] == ap2id) & (res['WEEK'] >= '201701')]['WEEK']
>     plt.figure()
>     plt.plot(ref_data1_x, ref_data1_pred, 'r')
>     plt.plot(ref_data1_x, ref_data1_real, 'b')
>     plt.xticks(rotation=70)
>     plt.xlabel("week")
>     plt.ylabel("Qty")
>     plt.title(item + " - " + ap2id)
> #     plt.savefig("../image/qty/Graph_" + str(datetime.datetime.now()) +"_" + ap2id +".png", format="PNG")
>     plt.show()
>
> for item in res['ITEM'].drop_duplicates():
>     for ap2id in res['AP2ID'].drop_duplicates():
>         make_plot(item, ap2id)
> ```

---

I'm making sales forecasting model and try to compare forecasting quantity and real one. Data is like below.
week is for x axis and y values are "qty_ap2" and "qty_pred"

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['WEEK', 'ITEM', 'AP2ID', 'QTY_AP2', 'QTY_PRED'])
df.loc[1]=['201801', 'a', '1', 5, 2]
df.loc[2]=['201802', 'a', '1', 8, 5]
df.loc[3]=['201803', 'a', '1', 1, 6]
df.loc[4]=['201804', 'a', '1', 0, 2]
df.loc[5]=['201805', 'a', '1', 4, 3]
```

thanks.

[Plot example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xuang.png)

Comment: Could you add the data that you are using or at least explain what it is and also give a brief explanation of what you are trying to plot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code does work for me:

```
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def make_plot(item, ap2id):
    ref_data1_pred = res[(res['ITEM'] == item) & (res['AP2ID'] == ap2id) & (res['WEEK'] >= '201701')]['QTY_PRED']
    ref_data1_real = res[(res['ITEM'] == item) & (res['AP2ID'] == ap2id) & (res['WEEK'] >= '201701')]['QTY_AP2']
    ref_data1_x = res[(res['ITEM'] == item) & (res['AP2ID'] == ap2id) & (res['WEEK'] >= '201701')]['WEEK']
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(ref_data1_x, ref_data1_pred, 'r')
    plt.plot(ref_data1_x, ref_data1_real, 'b')
    plt.xticks(rotation=70)
    plt.xlabel("week")
    plt.ylabel("Qty")
    plt.title(item + " - " + ap2id)
#     plt.savefig("../image/qty/Graph_" + str(datetime.datetime.now()) +"_" + ap2id +".png", format="PNG")
    plt.show()


res = pd.DataFrame(columns=['WEEK', 'ITEM', 'AP2ID', 'QTY_AP2', 'QTY_PRED'])
res.loc[1]=['201801', 'a', '1', 5, 2]
res.loc[2]=['201802', 'a', '1', 8, 5]
res.loc[3]=['201803', 'a', '1', 1, 6]
res.loc[4]=['201804', 'a', '1', 0, 2]
res.loc[5]=['201805', 'a', '1', 4, 3]
    
for item in res['ITEM'].drop_duplicates():
    for ap2id in res['AP2ID'].drop_duplicates():
        make_plot(item, ap2id)
```

and results in the following plot:

[image]

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your help. I made some mistakes in my code and I fixed it! Additionally, can I use specific x axis value? For example how can I do if I want to display only '201801', '201804' on the x axis? Could you help me?

Comment: to limit the range you can use `plt.xlim(xmin, xmax)` in your code, right above `plt.show()` command. However, since your abscissa is dates, it is good to get the current limits by using `xmin, xmax  = plt.xlim()`, depending on those you can adjust the limits.